# Some questions about written notation; "Small" notes, rest AND note, and an "unwarranted" natural?

Tags: sheet-music

[image]Key of G??

(Written for voice accompanied by Ukelele I believe)

[image]

Comment: These are zoomed a little too close to tell, but often this is done when there are rhythmic differences between different voices. Another explanation could be if they showed an alternate option, but this would usually be explained somewhere in the publication. Meanwhile the first picture seems to just be a [courtesy accidental](https://dictionary.onmusic.org/terms/964-courtesy_accidental). The melody of Zip-a-dee-doo-dah doesn't contain a Bb, but maybe it could be in response to a C7 chord or something of the sort earlier. Please edit to give photos that supply a bit more context.

Comment: @AndyBonner I think you meant "different verses," didn't you?

Comment: @AndyBonner added whole song, thank you for your help, has already shed light. Must be for different verses like phoog said, but could have gone either way without context, I think I get the idea!!!!!

Comment: There we go; and yes, I meant to type "verses" instead of "voices" (I gotta stop commenting on my phone!). And yes; the first two excerpt images are about having different rhythms the first vs the second time through (for the second image, the small dotted half is how the piece concludes, after having used the _D.S. al Fine_). But the courtesy accidental is utterly inexplicable. There's no B flat anywhere around, even in a chord, that might have made one think of playing a flat there.

Comment: @phoog thanks for the help man!!!

Comment: @AndyBonner Cool, that help A LOT actually. Also, I'm not crazy!!!! At least in this scenario haha, God bless man!!!!

Comment: @AndyBonner: Perhaps the editor gave a draft of the music to some people to test out, and many performers erroneously sang the note as Bb.  A major goal of a sheet music editor should be to maximize the likelihood that people will perform a piece correctly; that should be of higher priority than "theoretical" correctness.

Answer (score 6):

Taking bars 15/16. The normal notes (zip - a-dee-ay) show the rhythm expected for those words. The small accompanying notes represent won-der-ful-day. In bar 16, the last syllable/word is carried over (tied), but lasts a different length for each. Thus the need for normal and small dots.

Appertaining to that bar 16 - the 'big note' says hold for one more beat only, hence the one beat rest straight after, and the 'small note' means carry the word 'day' for an extra 3 beats. The one beat rest then fits in for both verses' words. There does need to be a rest somewhere, to fill the bar with its quota of 4 beats.

Regarding the natural sign - absolutely no need at all! It's usually put as a cautionary or courtesy accidental, reminding readers that it's not sharp or flat as in a previous bar, where the bar line would have cancelled it regardless. However, that note was never altered anyway, so it's totally superfluous in that place! Great old song!

Comment: Upvote for the only person who waited until the question was able to be confidently answered. Might add a bit more explanation though to the bar 16 bit just so it's crystal clear.

Comment: So I'm not (completely) crazy!!! Just "naturally" crazy lol. Thank you so much, this really helps clarify.

Comment: @JMMM - not totally, I guess! But it's good to point out to readers badly/inaccurately written stuff. That they will be aware that it exists, and can do something about it next time they see such.

Comment: @Tim we are still referring to the extra courteous courtesy natural when we say inaccurate, correct??

Comment: @Tim also, now that I think of it, what happens again in the 16th measure with the dotted half note; is it given "extra" time in that measure or???

Comment: @JMMM - yes, to the courtesy. Count up in bar 16. Dotted minim +crotchet rest, and crotchet, crotchet rest plus 2 crotchets. Maths done! Wouldn't have put the rest so high on the stave though.

Comment: I guess the crotchet rest being high is supposed to denote that it's only for one of the verses?? But that's sort of unconventional??? I think I'm lost again lol, coming back to this in a couple of hours...

Comment: @JMMM - the silly bit for me is that the rest coincides with both parts. Can't fathom...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147341/discussion-between-jmmm-and-tim).

Answer (score 4):

You've not shown us enough context for a certain answer.   But I'm pretty sure that the main notes in the vocal stave fit the first verse lyrics, the small notes are alternatives that fit the lyrics of a subsequent verse.

As to the accidental, I think that if you'd shown the preceding bar as well, it would have contained a B♭.  The natural is a helpful reminder, but not a strict notational requirement. A 'courtesy accidental', which is normally placed in parentheses.

Now we can see the whole song, that cautionary B♮ is interesting!  There's no preceding B♭ in the whole piece!    Perhaps the writer suspects we might sing a blues version!  Or, perhaps, in the version with full piano notation from which the vocal stave was lifted, a B♭ DID occur in the preceding bar, in the piano part.

Comment: Added whole song!!! Think you were right on the money with different verses, I think the natural maybe clarifying the B♭ at the end of the song??

Comment: @JMMM  Well... except that there isn't a Bb anywhere in the song!   There's a Db near the end.  That cautionary is a bit of a mystery!

Comment: I thought that Db WAS a Bb, lol how silly!! hank you for setting me straight!! How strange!!!!! The comment by supercat made one response up is the only thing that makes any sense to me so far then...

Answer (score 0):

Notes above one another with stems pointing away from each other are generally used if two voices are written in one staff. (Can include a note in one voice and rest in the other.)

Small notes in a song most often mean notes that are not meant to be sung, but played on an accompanying instrument as an ornament.

Not sure about the natural in parentheses, could be a courtesy accidental (to remind you that an accidental that was in place in the previous bar is no longer valid).

Any of these could also be used to denote differences if the melody slightly changes between verses/voltas, though I'm not making any claims about it being the correct way to denote such a thing.

Comment: "Small notes in a song most often mean notes that are not meant to be sung.."   They COULD mean that.  But in a multi-verse song, the 'most often' use will definitely be to show modification that fit the lyrics of another verse.

Comment: @Laurence In my experience that's more likely to just go without exact notation. But let's agree that both are definitely possibilities. You're sure right is seems very plausible in the third picture (though seeing the lyrics would help confirm it), but what confuses me is that in the second picture the notes seem to be the same size.

Comment: @Divinza Hymn tunes can be very sloppy about this sort of thing.  Popular music transcriptions are often more accurate!   The last note in the second example is a small note sitting behind a full-size one!   Not quite standard notation practice, but perfectly understandable, and it saves space.

Comment: @Laurence Yea I think it's for the different verses!!! Thanks man!!! God Bless!!!!!

Comment: @JMMM Easier to see in a picture that isn't so blurry. I don't see what's so incredibly funny about it, and it feels as if you're laughing at me (why would you need to inform me that you're laughing out loud).

Comment: @Divizna it's a turn of phrase, it more suggests the op is laughing at themselves or the situation they created!

Comment: @Divizna - don't take it personally. On this site it's extremely rare that contributors 'have a go' at each other. If they did, I'd have left years ago.

Comment: @Divizna my fault man, could see how my meaning/tone was unclear, and will remove, but yea preceding note is larger and it is easier to see in person or likely with a clearer picture!!!

Answer (score 0):

The natural sign in bracket signs is a courtesy accidental. It is just a reminder.

The two notes that form part of a second is probably the root and seventh of a chord chord that are played together with the third and fifth probably somewhere in the melody.

Then there is the interval of a unison. This is where two voices play the same note.

Comment: Just a reminder of *what*, though? The 'root and seventh' belong to two different verses, not a single chord. This seems like an inaccurate answer. There's no other (3rd and 5t) in the melody. Those notes *are* the melody, for two different verses.